# Non-existence of time operator in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-chemistry

In quantum mechanics, there is no operator for time instead of this we  we have $\psi(t)$ which is related to $\psi(0)$.

In a book, I read that if there is an operator for time, then it will not be Hermitian". 
I am not able to understand how exactly why? What is the reasoning behind this statement.

Comment: Hm, time is not an observable like energy or impulse.

Comment: Time is not just a physical value like any other. What would you want this operator to return, had it existed? Time in milliseconds since the Big Bang?

Comment: No, I mean time elapsed.

Comment: If you go to [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com) and search for "time operator" you will find plenty of answers...

Comment: Define "Hermitian".

Comment: I think part of the problem here is that relativistic quantum mechanics may be necessary to more adequately describe the role of time. Definitely should take it up with the physics folks.

Answer (score 3):

On the not Hermitian point.

Let $\hat{F}$ be a non-stationary observable (but does not depend explicitly on time $t$, hence $\partial \hat{F}/\partial t = 0)$. in the Heisenberg picture it satisfies the Heisenberg equation of motion for $\hat{F}$, namely
$$i \frac{d \hat{F}}{dt} = [\hat{F},\hat{H}] \tag{1}$$.

Now assume that whenever $d \hat{F}/dt \neq 0$ then it has an *inverse*
$$(d \hat{F}/dt)^{-1} = i([\hat{F},\hat{H}])^{-1}\tag{2}$$
Now, if
\begin{align}
[(d \hat{F}/dt)^{-1}, \hat{H}] &= 0 \\
\implies [([\hat{F},\hat{H}])^{-1},\hat{H}] &=0. 
\end{align}
Now introduce a *Time operator*, $\hat{T}$ as
\begin{align}
\hat{T} &= \frac{1}{2}\left(\hat{F}\left(\frac{d \hat{F}}{dt}\right)^{-1} + \left(\frac{d \hat{F}}{dt}\right)^{-1} \hat{F}\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\hat{F} ([\hat{F},\hat{H}])^{-1}+([\hat{F},\hat{H}])^{-1}\hat{F}\right)\tag{3}
\end{align}
Now using equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ into $(3)$ one finds that
$$[\hat{H}, \hat{T}] = i \tag{4}$$

That is, $\hat{T}$ and $\hat{H}$ form a canonically conjugate pair. Owing to the fact that the Hamiltonian spectrum is bounded from below, the time operator $\hat{T}$ is not self adjoint, in other words, not Hermitian.